# Game maker- How to add a period of invulnerability between collisions

Tags: game-maker

Completely new to game-maker and coding, trying to teach myself gml through following tutorials and what not. Anyway I followed a platformer enemy AI tutorial in; which when you hit the enemy object and are not above it the game will restart. I changed this to a line where the player loses 10 health as I wanted to add a health system into my game. However when the player comes into contact with the enemy, the player loses all of its health as the collision is constantly ticking. Anyway I was wondering how to add a few seconds in between each collision where the player is invulnerable? Thank you in advance
Below is the collision event code that I'm using:

```
if (y < other.y-vspd) {
with (other) {
instance_destroy();
}
vspd = -jspd;
} else {
global.playerhealth -= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a boolean such as `invulnerable` for the player's create event and set it to `false`. Then, add this code in the player's step event:

```
if (invulnerable){
    if (time < frames * seconds){
        time++;
    } else{
        invulnerable = false;
    }
}
```

Change `frames` to the frames-per-second/`room_speed` your game is on (defualt is 30).

Change `seconds` to the amount of seconds you want the player to be invulnerable.

Then you can change the code you have to:

```
if (y < other.y-vspd) {
with (other) {
instance_destroy();
}
vspd = -jspd;
} else if (!invulnerable) {
global.playerhealth -= 10;
invulnerable = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, after implementing everything I unfortunately still have the same problem. When I run into an enemy all of my players health will go instantly and the game restarts. I think there might be something wrong with my player code here is a link to it: (http://pastebin.com/5zQ14Dkv) could you have a look and see if you can see if anything is conflicting or if ive done something wrong?

Comment: Thanks so much I've been stuck with this problem for days!

Answer (score 0):

create a boolean variable (true or false) variable with a name like `canTakeDamage` that will be checked each time damage is dealt to the player. Then create an [alarm](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/000_using%20gamemaker/events/alarm%20event.html) which, after a certain amount of time will set the created `canTakeDamage` to true.

When the player is damaged, set `canTakeDamage` to false and execute the alarm. Implementing the variable could look something like this:

```
if (y < other.y-vspd) {
    with (other) {
    instance_destroy();
    vspd = -jspd;
} else {
    if (canTakeDamage) {
        global.playerhealth -= 10;
        alarm[0] = 200 // alarm[n] where n = alarm event you created
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this however when I ran the game the once the alarm time had ran out I would still lose all of my health practically instantly and when I took the initial alarm time off of the create variables then the player simply became invincible.

Comment: That's a bit weird. Could you post your full code for the player?

Comment: Thanks, I did this however when I ran the game the once the alarm time had ran out I would still lose all of my health practically instantly and when I took the initial alarm time off of the create variables then the player simply became invincible.  Here is all the code used in order of create variables, alarm and enemy collision:
`alarm[0] = 200
cantakedamage = 0;`     
`cantakedamage = 1;`     
`if (y < other.y-vspd) {
with (other) {
instance_destroy();
}
vspd = -jspd;
} else {
if (cantakedamage) {
global.playerhealth -= 10;
alarm[0] = 200;
}
}`